# kivy scrolling in grid layout of n rows

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I have a grid layout inside of a relative layout that i would like to have a variable number of rows with each row having a fixed length. this would use a scroll bar so a large amount of items could be included.
[image: here is the grid section of my page]

Below is the relevant part of my kv file, at the moment I am manually adding items, ideally I would  not have this hard coded but i'm not sure how...

```
    RelativeLayout:
        size_hint: 0.35, 1
        pos_hint: {"x": 0, "y": 0}
        TextInput: 
            id : inpSearch
            size_hint: 0.9,0.05
            pos_hint: {"x": 0, "y": 0.9}        
        GridLayout:
            size_hint: 1, 0.8
            pos_hint: {"x": 0, "y": 0.1}
            cols: 2 
            rows: 20

            Button:
                id : btnMov1
                text: 'Title'
            Button:
                id : btnRmv1
                text: 'Remove'
            Button:
                id : btnMov2       
                text: 'Title' 
            Button:
                id : btnRmv2       
                text: 'Remove'
            Button:
                id : btnMov3
                text: 'Title' 
            Button:
                id : btnRmv3
                text: 'Remove'
            Button:
                id : btnMov4       
                text: 'Title'
            Button:
                id : btnRmv4       
                text: 'Remove'
            Button:
                id : btnMov5
                text: 'Title'
            Button:
                id : btnRmv5
                text: 'Remove'
            Button:
                id : btnMov6       
                text: 'Title'
            Button:
                id : btnRmv6       
                text: 'Remove'
            Button:
                id : btnMov7
                text: 'Title'
            Button:
                id : btnRmv7
                text: 'Remove'
            Button:
                id : btnMov8
                text: 'Title'
            Button:
                id : btnRmv8       
                text: 'Remove'
            Button:
                id : btnMov9
                text: 'Title'
            Button:
                id : btnRmv9       
                text: 'Remove'
            Button:
                id : btnMov10
                text: 'Title'
            Button:
                id : btnRmv10       
                text: 'Remove'
            Button:
                id : btnMov11
                text: 'Title'
            Button:
                id : btnRmv11      
                text: 'Remove'
            Button:
                id : btnMov12
                text: 'Title'
            Button:
                id : btnRmv12      
                text: 'Remove'
            Button:
                id : btnMov13
                text: 'Title'
            Button:
                id : btnRmv13      
                text: 'Remove'
            Button:
                id : btnMov14
                text: 'Title'
            Button:
                id : btnRmv14      
                text: 'Remove'
            Button:
                id : btnMov15
                text: 'Title'
            Button:
                id : btnRmv15      
                text: 'Remove'
            Button:
                id : btnMov16
                text: 'Title'
            Button:
                id : btnRmv16      
                text: 'Remove'
            Button:
                id : btnMov17
                text: 'Title'
            Button:
                id : btnRmv17      
                text: 'Remove'
            Button:
                id : btnMov18
                text: 'Title'
            Button:
                id : btnRmv18      
                text: 'Remove'
            Button:
                id : btnMov19
                text: 'Title'
            Button:
                id : btnRmv19       
                text: 'Remove'
            Button: 
                id : btnMov20
                text: 'Title'
            Button:
                id : btnRmv20      
                text: 'Remove'

        Button:
            id : "btnAnm"
            text: "Add"
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.05
            pos_hint: {"x": 0, "y": 0.05}
```

I'm happy to keep this hard coded and have a fixed number of items but I would like to have a scroll bar so that I can fit more items in.

Comment: Did you try using a `for` loop ?

Comment: how is that relevant?

Comment: Try posting a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you are looking for by inserting the `GridLayout` into a `ScrollView` via `add_widget()`

[image]

**main.py**

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    pass


class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = MyGrid(size_hint_y=None, size_hint_x=1)
        layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))
        root = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, None), size=(Window.width, Window.height))
        root.add_widget(layout)
        return root

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myApp().run()
```

**my.kv**

```
<ScrollView>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 0, 0, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<GridLayout>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 0, 0
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    cols:2
    size: root.width, root.height


    TextInput: 
        id : inpSearch
        size_hint: 1, None

    Label:
        text: ''
    Button:
        id : btnMov1
        text: 'Title'
        size_hint: 1, None
        size: self.texture_size
        padding: 20, 15
    Button:
        id : btnRmv1
        text: 'Remove'
        size_hint: 1, None
        size: self.texture_size
        padding: 20, 15
    Button:
        id : btnMov2       
        text: 'Title' 
        size_hint: 1, None
        size: self.texture_size
        padding: 20, 15
    Button:
        id : btnRmv2       
        text: 'Remove'
        size_hint: 1, None
        size: self.texture_size
        padding: 20, 15
    Button:
        id : btnMov3
        text: 'Title' 
        size_hint: 1, None
        size: self.texture_size
        padding: 20, 15
    Button:
        id : btnRmv3
        text: 'Remove'
        size_hint: 1, None
        size: self.texture_size
        padding: 20, 15

    Button:
        id : "btnAnm"
        text: "Add"
        size_hint: 1, None
        size: self.texture_size
        padding: 20, 15
```

Note that for the widgets to display correctly you must specify additional properties as shown in the example.